# Basic alignment issue with CSS flexbox

Tags: html, css

I am creating my first sample webpage for a fictional company.  I am trying to use flexbox to display the three internal links in my `<nav>` element evenly spaced across the banner.  I verified the nav element spans across the entire page by changing background color, and so I'm left shaking my head at something I'm sure is fairly obvious to someone experienced.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-element {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a class="nav-element" href="#">Mission Statement</a>
    <a class="nav-element" href="#">Produce</a>
    <a class="nav-element" href="#">Helping Hands</a>
  </nav>
  <h1 class="title">portlandia farms</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to set the flex display property and justify-content on the nav container, not the links themselves:

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav-element {
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a class="nav-element" href="#">Mission Statement</a>
    <a class="nav-element" href="#">Produce</a>
    <a class="nav-element" href="#">Helping Hands</a>
  </nav>
  <h1 class="title">portlandia farms</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

As flexbox works you should put the flexbox related properties on the parent, to align it's children

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav-element {
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a class="nav-element" href="#">Mission Statement</a>
    <a class="nav-element" href="#">Produce</a>
    <a class="nav-element" href="#">Helping Hands</a>
  </nav>
  <h1 class="title">portlandia farms</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I really understand what you want, but I think you put the space-around in the wrong place, you need to put it inside nav tag, like this:

```
    <style>
        nav {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
        }
        
        .nav-element {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 1rem;
        }
    </style>
```